# Question on equivalent definitions of a convex function

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

As I was reading the proof of Jensen's inequality by Evans' book, I came across with this:

[image]

**Since $\;f\;$ is a convex function, for each $\;p \in \mathbb R\;$ there exists $\;r\in \mathbb R\;$ such that $$f(q) \ge f(p)+r(q-p).\quad\forall q \in \mathbb R$$**

However the definition of convex function as I know it is the following:

$\;f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R\;$ is convex if its domain is convex set and for all $\;x,y\;$ in its domain, and all $\;λ \in [0,1]\;$ we have $$f(λx+(1-λ)y) \le λf(x)+(1-λ)f(y).$$

Thus my question is, **why is the statement in Evans'book true?**

I also found this Theorem:
[image]

which states that if a function is convex then its graph should lie above then tangent line for all $\;x\;$ in its domain.Although in my case $\;f\;$ is not necessary differentiable and hence I can't assume $\;r=f'(p)\;$.

Last but not least, I found [this question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2347584/equivalent-definition-of-convex-functions) but these answers weren't that helpful for me.

I would really appreciate if somebody could explain to me all the above and save me from all this confusion!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you don't have derivative (a limit) just take $\liminf$ instead.

Comment: The gradient of the line $r$ should depend on the point $x_0$ (which is your $p$.)

Comment: @CalvinKhor I was referring to the $\;r\;$ in Evans' proof...

Comment: which indeed depends on $p$, what am I missing?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Maybe I'm missing something here. I get why it should depend on $\;x_0\;$ but I cannot see why $\;r\;$ in Evans book is equal to $\;f'(p)\;$ since there is no differentiability. Hope I made my confusion here more clear..

Comment: I made no claims that it should be of that form, just commenting on your sentence near the end  "on the one hand, in that post the number $r$
depends on $x_0$"

Comment: @CalvinKhor ok, I should edit it I guess

Comment: @treeleaf Could you please give me more details?

Comment: Maybe you'll find this useful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative Evans is using the fact that for convex functions the subdifferential at a point is not empty (which gives you the r).

Comment: @Uskebasi I think this is extremely helpful right now. Thanks.. I had no idea about subdifferential

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[It is well known that one equivalent definition of convexity is the statement that the gradient of secant lines increase.](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_Definitions_of_Convex_Real_Function) One way to write this down is as follows: for all $x<y<z$,

$$ \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} ≤ \frac{f(z)-f(y)}{z-y}$$
Let $y$ be fixed. Take $r := \liminf_{z\downarrow y} \frac{f(z) - f(y)}{z-y}, $ so that
$$ \frac{f(y) - f(x) }{y-x} ≤ r$$
Then $$f(x) ≥ f(y) + r(x-y), \quad x<y$$

Similarly if $r':= \limsup_{x\uparrow y}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$ one obtains 
 $$f(z) ≥ f(y)  + r'(z-y), \quad y<z$$
If $r'>r$ then $(r'-r)(x-y) ≤0 $ for $x<y$, so we can write
$$  f(x) ≥ f(y) + r(x-y) + (r'-r)(x-y) = f(y) + r'(x-y)  $$ and hence
$$ f(x) ≥ f(y) + r'(x-y) \quad ∀ x$$

If instead $r'<r$ we can similarly unify both inequalities, hence the result. Also, if $f$ were differentiable at $y$ then $r=r'=f'(y)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and your time! This is exactly what I needed...

Comment: Nice elementary proof. The only proof I knew used the support hyperplane theorem.

Comment: @Uskebasi If i recall correctly, something similar happens in that proof before applying Zorn's lemma.